# Filter SQL SELECT statement with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code a ripped somewhere but I am having issues trying to filter the results using a WHERE clause. What I would like to do is include a WHERE clause like WHERE name='John' in the statement to get only specific records associated with a person name and not the whole results of everybody as the code currently does. Here is my code:

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan,t.*
FROM customer t, 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r");
$data = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
$data[] = $r;
}
$i=0;
```

Comment: you can write 'Select ... , t.* FROM customer t where name = 'John''... what language are you using? plz tag it

Comment: This is obviously not Oracle. I've removed the tag.

Comment: why can't you simply use a where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WHERE clause belongs at the end:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan, t.*
FROM customer t, 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r WHERE t.name = 'John'");
```

Comment: you rock bro! Worked like magic! I did try same code at the end of the statement but I never did put the t. at the beginning of the column name. What does the "t." mean in the statement?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference actually. You have given the table `customer` the alias name `t`. You are also creating a one-record table on the fly which you call `r`. So, as there is more than one table in the query, I use the table qualifier to say where a column resides in. `name` belongs to `t`, so it's `t.name`.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using mysql_* functions

```
$query = "SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS urutan,t.*
FROM customer t, 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r  WHERE t.name=?"

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $query)
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s","Eric");
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

Comment: @e4c5...yea...mysql_ is depreciated and like I mentioned in my original post, I simply pasted everything as it was from the snippet I took it from. In my working environment, I have since moved on to mysqli_. I only have issues understanding PDO but, I will keep learning. Thank you so much for your response.